# Two (or more) aggregation relationships between two entities

Tags: uml, aggregation

Consider the following (abstract) situation:

Two entities. There are two aggregation relationships between the two entities.

The diagram looks like this:

[image: Two aggregation relationships]

I know this might sound vague, but is there anything wrong with this picture?

I mean, are there any (obvious) problems that could arise from this kind of design?

Or am I being paranoid and there's absolutely nothing wrong with two (or more) aggregation relationships between two entities?

Comment: SHARED aggregation, or SHARED, not aggregation as such.

Comment: (UML standard 2.9, p.109) The aggregation can be of 3 sorts: none(no diamond), shared(empty diamond), composite(black diamond). It is not correct to mix shared aggregation with aggregation. For example, you can easily have two or more parallel associations with shared aggregation in each and only one association with composite aggregation.

Comment: @Gangnus, my dear friend, we know that you have submitted yourself to UML speak, but please note that others, like myself, still desire speaking natural English, so we prefer using the UML terms "aggregation" and "composition", which is aggregation with non-shareable parts.

Comment: @gwag Thank you for a good word, friend. But I am afraid I can't agree. 1. Widely used error remains error. It is a fallacious argument to call for majority. 2. Of three most used UML tools only one uses "aggregation" instead of "shared". And it is not the mostly used EA. So, your are really in minority among professionals. So, even your fallacious argument is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me there is nothing wrong in such design. 
Your Entity2 will have a different role in each context that's all.

Comment: That's right, but he should better make this clear by adding two different role names that indicate the role played by the two parts of type Entity2.

Comment: I fully agree. This is essential in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the diagram. Here is a more meaningful example.
[image: Diagram]

-Kenji

Comment: I don't think your example is very meaningful. In which sense do you think a transaction is a part of a customer? I think a customer, which is a business object, participates in a transaction, which is a business event. In general, objects participate in events. But events are not part of objects!

Comment: OK, you're right. Then, how about I change the class name Customer to Transaction Manager ?

Comment: What is the sense of shared aggregation for relationship 1:1? Better admit existence of several current transactions.

Comment: @gwag 1. Transaction is not an event, it is an action, that has start and end and can continue for a long time. 2. Diamonds are empty. And shared aggregation does not suppose item(part as you say)-container relationship.

Comment: @Gangnus: Please note that an action is just a special type of event, therefore also a transaction is an event, no matter if it is instantaneous or not. Also, just look up (in a good dictionary or better in a philosophical encyclopedia such as [SEP](http://www.science.uva.nl/~seop/entries/mereology/)) what a part-whole (or parthood) relationship is.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the relationships are fulfilling really different roles (as you indictated by the numbering) I think it is a good approach, as you make them explicit.

Otherwise you could make use of the cardinality:

[image: Cardinality]